# Is the kissing number in $n$ dimensions always divisible by $n$? And what is the base of exponential growth of the kissing number?

Tags: lattices, packing-and-covering, sphere-packing, circle-packing

And why are the kissing numbers for 1, 2, 3, 4 and 8 dimensions all highly composite numbers?

Comment: 1st question: Probably not, but we don't have a proof.

Comment: For the question in the body (dimension 24 also): because the configurations achieving the kissing numbers in these dimensions are related to some nice lattice structure.  But why is it, we don't know ...

Comment: @Hao CHEN: Nope, not in 24 dimensions. In 24 dimensions the kissing number is 196560, which is divisible by 13 but not by 11, so it's not a highly composite number. (But it's close to being one.)

Comment: @user50746, my fault, I mean 196560 is also divisible by 24, didn't notice "highly composite".

Comment: @user50746, but it is indeed a "largely composite number"...is it?

Comment: So I have another question: how "composite" is the kissing number as dimension tends to infinity?

Comment: @Hao CHEN: Yep, 196560 is a largely composite number (though largely composite numbers are less interesting than highly composite numbers). But we can see that not all kissing numbers are largely composite numbers. For example: The kissing number in 5 dimensions is somewhere between 40 and 44, but there are no largely composite number between 40 and 44. Same thing for the kissing number in 7 dimensions: it's between 126 and 134 but there are no largely composite number between 126 and 134.

Comment: Yes. I would expect that the kissing number is less and less "composite" as dimension increases.  For the second question, a quick search shows that the kissing number is between $2^{0.2075d(1+o(1))}$ and $2^{0.401d(1+o(1))}$.  Not sure if there are any recent improvement.